# The second if else statement(for no. of attempts) doesnt seem to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

No alert pops out when the number of attempts is `2`. Is the `attempts` variable not getting increased? I am not able to find out. Please help.

```
var attempts = 0;
var $code = "youknowme";

$('.go').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#pass').val() === $code) {
        window.open("3.html");
    } else {
        alert("wrong code");
        attempts = attempts + 1;
    }   
});

if (attempts === 2) {      
    /*this code not working*/
    alert("You have last chance left");
} else if (attempts === 3) {
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: Can I see your html?

Comment: Because `attempts` equals `0` when that code executes.  Because you *just defined it as `0`*.

Comment: Now that I've formatted your code properly you can see that you only check `attempts === 2` on load. I guess you need to actually put it in the `click` handler.

Comment: Is that really a client side password check? You know it's *really* not secure as any user can see the $code value ?

Comment: There should be a closing reason "bug is obvious as soon as the code is properly formatted"

Answer (score 3):

That is because you need to put the code inside the click event. As it stands the if statement is checked only once, and that happens to be just after you set the number of attempts to 0.

If you formatted your code correctly this would have made it a lot easier to spot.

This is how is should be:

```
var attempts=0;
var $code="youknowme";

$('.go').on('click',function(){

    if($('#pass').val()===$code){
        window.open("3.html");
    }else{
        alert("wrong code");
        attempts=attempts+1;
    }   

    /* code is now executed each time the click event occurs */
    if(attempts===2){
        alert("You have last chance left");
    }
    else if(attempts===3){
        window.close();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be inside function:

```
var attempts=0;
var $code="youknowme";

$('.go').on('click',function(){
    if($('#pass').val()===$code){
        window.open("3.html");
    }else{
        alert("wrong code");
        attempts=attempts+1;
    }   
    if(attempts===2){      /*this code not working*/
        alert("You have last chance left");
    }
    else if(attempts===3){
        window.close();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements need to be inside of your onclick listener. They aren't being executed when being clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

The 'if' statement is outside of the 'click' function. 
```
    $('.go').on('click', function() {
        if ($('#pass').val() === $code) {
            window.open("3.html");
        } else {
            alert("wrong code");
            attempts = attempts + 1;
        }

```
    if (attempts === 2) {      
        /*this code not working*/
        alert("You have last chance left");
    } else if (attempts === 3) {
        window.close();
    }
});
```

```